# Can I have a primary key and a separate clustered index together?

Tags: database, database-design, indexing, primary-key, clustered-index

Let's assume I already have a primary key, which makes sure uniqueness. My primary key is also ordering index for the records. However, I am curious about **the primary key's task in physical order of records in the disk (if there is)**. And the actual question is **can I have a separate clustered index for these records?**

Comment: I assume you are talking about SQL Server? Not all DBMS have a concept of a "clustered index".

Comment: So you **are** talking about SQL Server?

Comment: I have raised the question in a general way (theoretically), but I want to hear an answer for a particular case too.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name _Not all DBMS have a concept of a "clustered index"_ Let me just mention that Oracle (through "index-organized tables") and MySQL/InnoDB also support clustering. Though, Oracle ties it more strongly to the PK than MS SQL Server, while under InnoDB it cannot be turned-off at all. PostgreSQL has "hybrid" clustering - you need to [resort the table periodically](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.2/static/sql-cluster.html) to maintain the clustering order. DB2 and Informix also support some forms of clustering, though I'm not too familiar with that...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It depends on your dbms. Not all of them implement clustered indexes. Those that do are liable to implement them in different ways. As far as I know, every platform that implements clustered indexes also provides ways to choose which columns are in the clustered index, although often the primary key is the default.

In SQL Server, you can create a nonclustered primary key and a separate clustered index like this.

```
create table test (
  test_id integer primary key nonclustered,
  another_column char(5) not null unique clustered
  );
```

I think that the closest thing to this in Oracle is an index organized table. I could be wrong.  It's not quite the same as creating a table with a clustered index in SQL Server.

You can't have *multiple* clustered indexes on a single table in SQL Server. A table's rows can only be stored in one order at a time. Actually, I suppose you *could* store rows in multiple, distinct orders, but you'd have to essentially duplicate all or part of the table for each order. (Although I didn't know it at the time I wrote this answer, [DB2 UDB supports multiple clustered indexes](http://www.ibmsystemsmag.com/aix/administrator/highavailability/The-Luster-of-Data-Clustering/), and it's quite an old feature.  Its [design and implementation](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/db2luw/v9r5/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.db2.luw.admin.partition.doc/doc/c0007201.html) is quite different from SQL Server.)

A primary key's job is to guarantee uniqueness. Although that job is often done by creating a unique index on the primary key column(s), strictly speaking uniqueness and indexing are two different things with two different aims.  Uniqueness aims for data integrity; indexing aims for speed.

A primary key declaration isn't intended to give you any information about the order of *rows* on disk. In practice, it usually gives you some information about the order of *index entries* on disk. (Because primary keys are usually implemented using a unique index.)

If you SELECT rows from a table that has a clustered index, you still can't be assured that the rows will be *returned to the user* in the same order that they're stored on disk. Loosely speaking, the clustered index helps the query optimizer *find* rows faster, but it doesn't control the order in which those rows are returned to the user. The *only* way to guarantee the order in which rows are returned to the user is with an explicit `ORDER BY` clause. (This seems to be a fairly frequent point of confusion. A lot of people seem surprised when a bare SELECT on a clustered index doesn't return rows in the order they expect.)

Comment: _"but you'd have to essentially duplicate the table for each order. I don't know of any dbms that does that."_ Actually, the similar effect can be easily accomplished by an index that covers the whole table (i.e. contains all fields). If clustered table is a B-Tree, this index is simply another B-Tree that contains the same data, but in different order, so suitable queries don't need to touch the original B-Tree at all. In practice, of course, you probably won't put all the fields in the secondary index - just those that are needed for the actual queries (+ PK fields, which are implied).

Comment: *"Actually, the similar effect can be easily accomplished by an index that covers the whole table"* The leaf nodes of SQL Server's clustered  indexes are data pages. The leaf nodes of its nonclustered indexes are index pages that point to data. I get what you're saying, but they're not similar with respect to physical layout and disk I/O, which was the point of the question.

Comment: _"...that point to data"_ Secondary indexes in clustered tables are organized differently from indexes in heap-based tables. There is no heap to point to. Instead, they they "point" to the main B-Tree by holding a copy of the clustering key fields. Or at least this is how Oracle and InnoDB do it - is there something special about SQL Server I wasn't aware of? I would expect the performance to be similar between a clustering index and a secondary index that covers the query (covering avoids double-lookup into the clustering index). Perhaps this was not your experience?

Comment: @BrankoDimitrijevic: Can you test it? (No Windows servers here.) I'd expect there to be more disk I/O for a secondary index that covered a whole table, because fewer index entries would fit on a data page.

Comment: I finally got around to testing it, and the results seem to indicate the covering secondary index is **not** "fatter" than the table. In fact (to my surprise) it even seem slightly slimmer. I certainly don't consider myself an expert when it comes to intricacies of MS SQL Server specific syntax, so I'd appreciate if you could take a look at [my measurements](http://stackoverflow.com/a/12819142/533120) and let me know if I made any mistakes...

Comment: @BrankoDimitrijevic: The only thing that jumped out at me was testing with a really narrow table. I'd rather see a test with a few varchar columns. But I really appreciate your doing that work. Interesting stuff.

Comment: When measuring the time, I seem to have made a mistake of exceeding the resolution of `SYSDATETIME()`. When I increased the number of iterations to 10000, I got slightly different results where table (181.3 ms) seems a little faster than the index (195.2 ms). The difference is probably not large enough to be of practical concern, but its there. Using wider (varchar) fields makes this difference slightly more pronounced (254.7 ms / 296.9 ms). In both cases, index is smaller than table. I have edited my answer accordingly.

Answer (score 3):

This is an attempt at testing the size and performance characteristics of a [covering](http://use-the-index-luke.com/sql/glossary/covering-index) secondary index on a clustered table, as per [discussion with @Catcall](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12730056/533120).

All tests were done on MS SQL Server 2008 R2 Express (inside a fairly underpowered VM).

### Size

First, I crated a clustered table with a secondary index and filled it with some test data:

```
CREATE TABLE THE_TABLE (
    FIELD1 int,
    FIELD2 int NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT THE_TABLE_PK PRIMARY KEY (FIELD1)
);

CREATE INDEX THE_TABLE_IE1 ON THE_TABLE (FIELD2) INCLUDE (FIELD1);

DECLARE @COUNT int = 1;
WHILE @COUNT <= 1000000 BEGIN
    INSERT INTO THE_TABLE (FIELD1, FIELD2) VALUES (@COUNT, @COUNT);
    SET @COUNT = @COUNT + 1;
END;

EXEC sp_spaceused 'THE_TABLE';
```

The last line gave me the following result...

```
name        rows        reserved    data        index_size  unused
THE_TABLE   1000000     27856 KB    16808 KB    11008 KB    40 KB
```

So, the index's B-Tree (11008 KB) is actually smaller than the table's B-Tree (16808 KB).

### Speed

I generated a random number within the range of the data in the table, and then used it as criteria for selecting a whole row from the table. This was repeated 10000 times and the total time measured:

```
DECLARE @I int = 1;
DECLARE @F1 int;
DECLARE @F2 int;
DECLARE @END_TIME DATETIME2;
DECLARE @START_TIME DATETIME2 = SYSDATETIME();

WHILE @I <= 10000 BEGIN

    SELECT @F1 = FIELD1, @F2 = FIELD2
    FROM THE_TABLE
    WHERE FIELD1 = (SELECT CEILING(RAND() * 1000000));

    SET @I = @I + 1;
END;

SET @END_TIME = SYSDATETIME();
SELECT DATEDIFF(millisecond, @START_TIME, @END_TIME);
```

The last line produces an average time (of 10 measurements) of 181.3 ms.

When I change the query condition to: `WHERE FIELD2 = ...`, so the secondary index is used, the average time is 195.2 ms.

Execution plans:

[image]

[image]

So the performance (of selecting on the PK versus on the covering secondary index) seems to be similar. For much larger amounts of data, I suspect the secondary index could possibly be slightly faster (since it seems more compact and therefore cache-friendly), but I didn't hit that yet in my testing.

### String Measurements

Using `varchar(50)` as type for `FIELD1` and `FIELD2` and inserting strings that vary in length between 22 and 28 characters gave similar results.

The sizes were:

```
name        rows        reserved    data        index_size  unused
THE_TABLE   1000000     208144 KB   112424 KB   95632 KB    88 KB
```

And the average timings were: 254.7 ms for searching on `FIELD1` and 296.9 ms fir `FIELD2`.

### Conclusion

If a clustered table has a covering secondary index, that index will have space and time characteristics similar to the table itself (possibly slightly slower, but not by much). If effect, you'll have two B-Trees that sort their data differently, but are otherwise very similar, achieving your goal of having a "second cluster".